# dockerfile: it is good to `chmod 777 entrypoint`?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it safe/necessary to do the following:

```
RUN chmod 777 /cassandra-start.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/cassandra-start.sh"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It is not safe.

- If the shell executing this script is bash, it can and will (in some circumstances) read updates to the script it is already interpreting, so even if changes are scoped by Docker's copy-on-write nature to a single instance, the behavior of that instance can be modified by code which has minimal (even `nobody`) permissions within it.
- In most Docker filesystem backends, guest filesystems are accessible on the host. Leaving executable files world-writable on the host means that any user with `+x` permissions to its parent directories can modify that content.

#### It is not necessary.

- Execution of a script requires `+r` and `+x`. It does not in any respect require `+w`. Thus, `755` is generally sufficient.
- If you have runtime configuration which takes place based on programatically modifying a script, the way to do this without permitting shell injection attacks is instead to modify a data file that script reads (and to ensure that the manner in which this data file is interpreted does not contain any `eval`-equivalent practices). That is to say, if you currently have code modifying a variable in your script with `sed -e 's/variable=.*/variable=foo/'`, have your script contain `variable=$(<var.file)`, and modify the contents of `var.file`.